# Rooms/Channels and userId in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm building a multiplayer, turn-based game using meteor.js. The application will handle multiple games, so I'd like to separate my users into rooms. 
I've done it before using socket.io channels, but I'm struggling to understand how it should be done in Meteor.

The flow I'd like to achieve is:

1. User visits http://localhost:3000/join/userId
2. I make a server-side call to an external API using "sessionId" as parameter, getting user's userId, his assigned roomId and an array of allowed userId's for this room
3. I'd like to create a room with roomId for the user or join him to an existing one. I know I should create a 'Rooms' collection, but I don't know how to tie users to my rooms and publish messages only to those present in the given room.

I'd like to avoid using 'accounts' package, because I don't need authorisation on my side - it'll be handled by step #2 mentioned above - but if the easiest and cleanest way of doing it involves adding this package, I can change my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Rooms` collection could look like:

```
{
    _id: "<auto-generated>",
    roomId: "roomId",
    users: [ "user1", "user2", "user3", ... ],
    messages: [
        { message: "", userId: "" },
        { message: "", userId: "" },
        { message: "", userId: "" },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The server-side API call returns

`userId` and `roomId` among other information.

So you can do a

```
Rooms.update({ roomId: roomId }, { $push: { users: userId } }, { upsert: true });
```

This would push the user into the exiting room or create a new room and add the user.

Your publish function could look like:

```
Meteor.publish("room", function(roomId) {
    // Since you are not using accounts package, you will have to get the userId using the sessionId that you've specified or some other way.
    // Let us assume your function getUserId does just that.

    userId: getUserId( sessionId );
    return Rooms.find({ roomId: roomId, users: userId });

    // Only the room's users will get the data now.

});
```

Hope this helps.